# Can categories with suspension be considered as Cat-enriched presheaves over certain strict 2-category?

Tags: category-theory, stable-homotopy-theory, enriched-category-theory, 2-categories

I came across the concept of a category with suspension $(\mathcal{C},\Sigma)$ which is defined as a category $\mathcal{C}$ together with an endofunctor $\Sigma:\mathcal{C}\rightarrow \mathcal{C}$. We call $(\mathcal{C},\Sigma)$ (strictly) stable if $\Sigma$ is an isomorphism of categories.

The "correct" morphism $(F,\varphi):(\mathcal{C},\Sigma)\rightarrow(\mathcal{D},T)$ between categories with suspension will be called weakly stable functor, which is a functor $F:\mathcal{C}\rightarrow\mathcal{D}$ with a natural isomorphism $\varphi:F\Sigma\xrightarrow{\sim} TF$. And $(F,\varphi)$ will be further called stable if $F\Sigma=TF$ and $\varphi=\operatorname{id}$.

There are two universal ways to make a category with suspension stable, which are dual to each other. One is called costabilization (the other stabilization of course), which enjoys the following universal property:

1. The costabilization of a category with suspension $(\mathcal{C},\Sigma)$ is a stable category with suspension $(\mathcal{RC},\hat\Sigma)$ together with a weakly stable functor $(R,\gamma):(\mathcal{RC},\hat\Sigma)\rightarrow(\mathcal{C},\Sigma)$ s.t.
2. For any stable category with suspension $(\mathcal{D},T)$ and weakly stable functor $(F,\varphi):(\mathcal{D},T)\rightarrow(\mathcal{C},\Sigma)$, there exists a unique stable functor $\tilde{F}:(\mathcal{D},T)\rightarrow(\mathcal{RC},\hat\Sigma)$ s.t. $R\tilde{F}=F, \gamma\tilde{F}=\varphi$ strictly.

These concepts makes think of the action of a group (or monoid) on a set and to take the invariants/coinvariants. But one can also think of an action of a monoid $M$ on a set as a presheaf on $M$ considered as a category with one object, and the process of taking (co)invariants as taking (co)limits.

I'm having some trouble understanding the construction of (co)stabilization so want to make some analogies. I think a category with suspension will be equivalently a $\mathbf{Cat}$-valued presheave over some 2-categorical flavored structure, and the (co)stabilization will be simply taking some 2-(co)limits, but I can't be sure what the framework is. Can somebody help me?

The references of (co)stabilizations would be [Remark 4 in Co-Gorenstein algebras by
Sondre Kvamme, Rene Marczinzik](https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.00274v2) or [Stable homotopy categories by Alex Heller](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bulletin-of-the-american-mathematical-society-new-series/volume-74/issue-1/Stable-homotopy-categories/bams/1183529378.full)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the intuition you have has been formalized for the first time in 1969 by Miles Tierney (but I think it was "known" to algebraic topologists from before?) in https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/BFb0101425

Consider in particular its [chapter 2](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/BFb0101427), which can be summarized as follows, when monoids are considered as categories with a single object.

A category with endomorphism can be regarded as a functor $\mathbb{N}\to Cat$ (more generally, an object with endomorphism is a functor $\mathbb{N}\to \mathcal C$, i.e. a representation of the monoid $(\mathbb N, +,0)$ of natural numbers into $\mathcal C$).

A category with *auto*morphism is, similarly, a functor $(\mathbb Z,+,0)\to Cat$ (a representation of the additive group of integers).

Clearly, there is a forgetful functor $J : Cat^{\mathbb Z} \to Cat^{\mathbb N}$, and the two universal stabilization procedures that you have in mind are nothing but the left and the right adjoint to $J$. If you note that $J$ is just the precomposition with the obvious inclusion $j : \mathbb N \hookrightarrow \mathbb Z$, the left and right adjoints to $J$ can also be characterized as left and right Kan extensions, respectively, along $j$.

What Tierney does in chapter 2 of that small book is to describe the left adjoint explicitly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and reference! But there may be one problem that this  treatment lost the information of 2-morphisms, in the way that it didn’t consider weakly stable functors and the universal property also didn’t mention natural transformation. So I think there should be some 2-categorical framework lurking around.

Comment: Yes, I thought about adding a paragraph clarifying that Tierney's construction is strict, while yours is pseudo: but apart from some coherence all universal properties should transport to up-to-canonical-iso-filling ones. In my answer, replace "functor" with "pseudofunctor" and adjoint with "pseudoadjoint" and you should keep information on 2-morphisms as well. There's a little bit of work if you want to dot all the i's, but I think it won't be painful. (By the way, a *lax* functor $\mathbb N \to Cat$ is itself a very interesting object.)

Comment: May I ask whether I can do this in the context of strict 2-categories rather than bicategories? Sorry I'm not very familar with those subtleties between them. I can see that if we consider $\mathbb{N}$ as a strict 2-category with one object, then a strict 2-functor (equivalently $\mathbf{Cat}$-enriched functor) $\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbf{Cat}$ would be a category with suspension and a $\mathbf{Cat}$-enriched natural transformation between these functors would be a stable functor (please correct me if I'm wrong). Is this the reason to use bicategories?

Comment: Oh, by unraveling the definitions I might have a grasp of what you mean. This seems to have to happen in bicategories with pseudofuntors. The lax functor you mentioned, if I understand right, might involve with an element in the center of the category?